# Detecting Scrolling actions in a WebView

Tags: android, events, webview

I've spent quite a bit of time googling this but haven't found any good explanation.

My aim is to be able to log actions like scroll up, scroll down, zoom in and zoom out etc inside a WebView.

For example, if a User opens a page (in a WebView), my app should be able to log the number of times he scrolls up or down, or zooms in and out of the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have got the solution of this then plz let me know I have the same question?